# Format number with JSTL and no rounding

Tags: java, jstl, number-formatting

I need to format number using `<fmt:formatNumber/>` jstl tag. The output should be restricted to 3 places after the decimal point, but rounding isn't allowed, so using the attribute `maxFractionDigits="3"` isn't appropriate, cause it rounds the number.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What would you like it to do instead of rounding? truncating? throw an exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could subtract 0.0005 from the number before formatting it. That way the rounding will be equivalent to truncating the original number to 3 decimal places.

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${myNumber - 0.0005}" maxFractionDigits="3"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've used string processing instead, but it's an interesting option

Answer (score 2):

Design your own tag or EL function that truncates the number before formatting it. Or just design a tag or function that truncates the number, and pass the result to `<fmt:formatNumber/>`. Something like

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${myFn:truncate(theNumber, 3)"/>
```