# JSTL Don't Round on minFractionDigits

Tags: spring-mvc, format, jstl

I have a number that I want to be truncated not rounded. It seems like when I use minFractionalDigit=2 my number gets rounded on the third decimal.

For example:

```
What happens:

1.123 => 1.12
1.145 => 1.15
1 => 1.00

What I want: 

1.123 => 1.12
1.145 => 1.14
1 => 1.00    


<fmt:formatNumber value="${myNumber}" minFractionDigits="2" type="currency" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13181024/2782261) is a front-end approach that circumvents rounding.

Another approach would be to format the values on the back-end like so:

```
BigDecimal formattedNumber = new BigDecimal(myNumber);
format.setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN);

request.setAttribute("myNumber", formattedNumber);
```

Which you can then reference in an expression:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${myNumber}" minFractionDigits="2" type="currency" />
```

Comment: I'll probably end up doing it the way that circumvents rounding. Thanks